# Algorithm to reshuffle list/array so all entries are separated from former neighbors?

Tags: algorithm, shuffle

This isn't quite derangements (reshuffling with nothing staying in the same slot,) but it's similar.

I have a list from, say, (0, ... , 23) and I want to reshuffle it so x and x+1 are not in adjacent indices. In fact, I would prefer they not be only 2 apart.

Is there an algorithmic way to do things, or is generating things randomly until something works the only way to go? Python code below for making sure ex-neighbors are 3 apart. The average seems to be 60 tries, which is acceptable to me.

```
import random

list_length = 30
too_close_distance = 2

def acceptable_distance(a_list):
    for x in range(0, len(a_list) - 1):
        if abs(a_list.index(x+1) - a_list.index(x)) <= too_close_distance:
            return False
    return True

my_list = list(range(0, list_length))

while not acceptable_distance(my_list):
    random.shuffle(my_list)

print(my_list)
```

Comment: Is randomness a fundamental application requirement here? If not, you could always use a pre-determined permutation that "looks" random and fulfills your requirement. Or a set of pre-determined permutations from which you select one randomly.

Answer (score 2):

For a very simple version that gives you only small distances: take every four-long chunk of values and rearrange them in place as follows:

```
ABCD -> CADB
```

No adjacencies are preserved within this chunk, and the outermost elements have changed, so no adjacencies with neighboring chunks are preserved either.

If your list is not a multiple of four in length, the last few can be dealt with as a 5, 6, or 7-length chunk as follows:

```
ABCDE -> CEADB
ABCDEF -> CEADFB
ABCDEFG -> FCGEADB
```

To do better I think you'll have to better define your problem. "In fact, I would prefer they not be only 2 apart." is really too vague a metric for driving algorithm design. Do you want to maximize total distance between former neighbors, with the constraint that no two can be adjacent afterwards? Or to maximize the minimum distance between former neighbors?

One thing that might work well is to just put all of the even-indexed elements in front of all the odd-indexed elements(i.e., `02461357`).

In general "Try it randomly and check if you meet the constraint" is usually something that will get you in trouble in the long run. It's an easy algorithm to write and it's worth having in your toolkit, but you'll usually find that you get weird performance or even non-halting issues under situations that are difficult to debug or describe.

Comment: Extension to your method: Do the 4-swap as you recommend. Then, randomly shuffle the fourples. You can go one more step and randomly move around the inner two items from each fourple. For example, given `[1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8]`, you have `[(2,4,1,3),(6,8,5,7)]`, "Shuffle" to get `[(6,8,5,7),(2,4,1,3)]`. At this point, you swap the 2nd and 3rd items from any fourple with the 2nd and 3rd items in any other. For example, `[(6,1,4,7),(2,8,5,3)]`.

Answer (score 0):

First I describe a method without randomness, then I explain how to make things more random.

#### If you don't care about randomness

Assuming you don't care about randomness, and just want to make it so that elements that used to be close will now be far apart:

- Arrange your list into a square;
- Transpose rows and colums;
- Put the square back into a list.

This will not exactly maximise the minimum distance between former direct neighbours, but instead, it will also put some distance between former near neighbours.

Example:

```
start
ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ

square
ABCDE
FGHIJ
KLMNO
PQRST
UVWXY
Z

transpose
AFKPUZ
BGLQV
CHMRW
DINSX
EJOTY

unsquare
AFKPUZBGLQVCHMRWDINSXEJOTY
```

In python using [more_itertools](https://pypi.org/project/more-itertools/):

```py
from math import isqrt  # integer square root
from more_itertools import chunked, interleave_longest

def square_transpose_unsquare(seq):
    r = isqrt(len(seq))
    return list(interleave_longest(*chunked(seq, r)))

for seq in ('ABCD', 'ABCDE', 'ABCDEFGHIJ', 'ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ'):
    print(seq, '-->', ''.join(square_transpose_unsquare(seq)))

ABCD --> ACBD
ABCDE --> ADBEC
ABCDEFGHIJ --> AEIBFJCGDH
ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ --> AGMSYBHNTZCIOUDJPVEKQWFLRX
```

#### If you want some randomness

You can shuffle the rows of the square before transposing:

- Arrange your list into a square;
- Shuffle the rows randomly;
- Transpose rows and colums;
- Put the square back into a list.

Example:

```
start
ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ

square
ABCDE
FGHIJ
KLMNO
PQRST
UVWXY
Z

shuffle rows randomly
FGHIJ
PQRST
UVWXY
ABCDE
Z
KLMNO

transpose
FPUAZK
GQVB L
HRWC M
ISXD N
JTYE O

unsquare
FPUAZKGQVBLHRWCMISXDNJTYEO
```

In python:

```py
from math import isqrt  # integer square root
from more_itertools import chunked, interleave_longest
from random import shuffle

def square_shuffle_transpose_unsquare(seq):
    r = isqrt(len(seq))
    square = list(chunked(seq, r))
    shuffle(square)
    return list(interleave_longest(*square))

for seq in ('ABCD', 'ABCDE', 'ABCDEFGHIJ', 'ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ'):
    print(seq, '-->', ''.join(square_shuffle_transpose_unsquare(seq)))

ABCD --> CADB
ABCDE --> ACEBD
ABCDEFGHIJ --> DAGJEBHFCI
ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ --> KFPUAZLGQVBMHRWCNISXDOJTYE
```

Comment: The square method doesn't maximize minimum distance between neighbors - for instance, if you compare the 4-by-4 case, you get a distance of 4. However, if you alternated odd and even (equivalent to transposing a 2-by-8 rectangle) you would get a minimum distance of 8. (Yours does something related and possibly desirable, taking into account not just direct neighbors but "near neighbors" in the original list -I think it maximizes something, but I'm not sure what that something is, formally.)

Comment: @EdwardPeters You are completely right!! Thank you for this head-scratching moment.